# Algorithms for enumeration all permutations given a cycle structure

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I need to enumerate on all permutations of size N, but with specific cycle sizes - cycles of length 1 (that is, stationary points), 2 and K (a parameter). I need to go over all permutations with such cycles - there can be more than one cycle of each size if N is large enough.

I tried to look for such algorithms in the literature but couldn't. I would appreciate any pointers to such algorithms.

Comment: Similar apologies - do you simply want to generate all distinct permutations corresponding to cycles of some length?

Answer (score 2):

I think that this problem falls into the gap of being neither hard nor elegant to solve. No matter. There's a recursive strategy that accepts a multiset of cycle sizes, loops over cycle sizes, includes one fixed element and the appropriate number of others, and recurses on the remaining elements.

Lightly tested, unoptimized Python 3:

```
import itertools

def enumerate_perms(cycle_sizes, elements):
    assert isinstance(cycle_sizes, list)
    assert all(isinstance(cycle_size, int) for cycle_size in cycle_sizes)
    assert all(cycle_size >= 1 for cycle_size in cycle_sizes)
    assert isinstance(elements, list)
    assert len(elements) == sum(cycle_sizes)
    if not elements:
        yield {}
        return
    for cycle_size in set(cycle_sizes):
        remaining_cycle_sizes = cycle_sizes[:]
        remaining_cycle_sizes.remove(cycle_size)
        for others_tuple in itertools.permutations(elements[1:], cycle_size - 1):
            remaining_elements = elements[1:]
            for other in others_tuple:
                remaining_elements.remove(other)
            others = list(others_tuple)
            others.append(elements[0])
            for subperm in enumerate_perms(remaining_cycle_sizes, remaining_elements):
                for i in range(cycle_size):
                    subperm[others[i - 1]] = others[i]
                yield subperm

print(list(enumerate_perms([2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])))
```

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there was a cool and surprisingly slick way to solve this. I guess your definition of 'neither hard nor elegant' is correct. The number of cycles changes (as long as the sum of all cycles <= perm size, and the are all of the legal sizes). I'll do the unelegant work...

Comment: @zmbq If 1 is a cycle size, you can just rip out all of the logic having to do with cycle sizes and iterate through all of the cycle sizes less than or equal to the number of remaining elements.

Comment: No, no, cycle sizes must be 1, 2 or K (or 1 and K, depending on some input). I'll need to loop carefully.